# NSObject data to UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsobject

I created a class with some properties. In the storyboard I have a tableview controller. I want to pass data from the class to the tableview. In each cell I have some labels. I want to fill the data but I haven't success with the arrays. Can you please help me.

So I have a City class with some properties for ex. property1, property2, which are labels

```
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface DACityObject : NSObject {

    NSNumber *ID;
    NSString *name;
    NSNumber *temperature;
    NSNumber *minimumTemperature;
    NSNumber *maximumTemperature;
    NSString *iconName;
}

@property (strong,nonatomic) NSNumber *ID;
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSString *name;
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSNumber *temperature;
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSNumber *minimumTemperature;
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSNumber *maximumTemperature;
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSString *iconName;

@end
```

and .m file

```
    #import "DACityObject.h"

@implementation DACityObject

@synthesize ID,name,temperature,minimumTemperature,maximumTemperature,iconName;



@end
```

DACityCell.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface DACityCell : UITableViewCell


@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *name;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *temperature;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *minimumTemperature;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *maximumTemperature;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *iconName;


@end
```

DACityCell.m

```
#import "DACityCell.h"

@implementation DACityCell
@synthesize name,temperature,minimumTemperature,maximumTemperature,iconName;

- (void)awakeFromNib {


}


- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];
    self.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0,45,75,75);
}



@end
```

How can I create a data for example 3 cities and put it in the table view in my MainController?

Comment: Why duplicate those attributes in both classes?  Better is to pass `DACityObject` to the cell and say "here, use this data".

Comment: can you please give me clearer answer because I'm newbie :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's say you've already created your 3 data via the class object `DACityObject`, all you have to do now is to place them in an array say dataArray `(NSMutableArray)` and call them in the method `cellForRowAtIndexPath` in your class that has the `UITableView`, then just call your custom tableview cell.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";

    // extract data here 
    DACityObject *dataObject = [dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    DACityCell *cell = (DACityCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) 
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"DACityCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    } 

    cell.name.text = dataObject.name;
    cell.temperature.text = dataObject.temperature;
    .
    .
    .... etc.

    return cell;
}
```